# Real holomorphic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Like analytic functions we have studied real analytic functions but I have never heard this word*REAL HOLOMORPHIC* Functions.Is the concept of Holomorphic function absent in real analysis?if it is not then give example....
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know,  *holomorphic* describes functions of complex variables (only).  It turns out these functions are analytic.

Functions of a real variable can be differentiable without being (real) analytic. For instance a "bump function".